# Matlab throws a Module Error using 'pyrunfile'

Tags: python, matlab, dll, scipy, spyder

I don't know much about Python, so I hope someone here can help me. I'm trying to run a python file from Matlab that works without problems in Spyder. In Matlab I only use the following two lines:

```
pyenv('version', 'C:\Users\XXX\.conda\envs\Deep\python.exe')
pyrunfile('one_component_model.py')
```

The code I want to run comes from [here](https://github.com/XiaqiongFan/DeepCID/blob/master/one_component_model.py). When running the command I get the following error:

```
Python Error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing qhull
```

The Error occurs in: 'C:\Users\XXX\ .conda\envs\Deep\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\ __init__.py' in line 98:

```
from .qhull import *
```

I've already spent half the day reading up on this today, but haven't found a solution. Does anyone know what the error means here? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I recommend looking into the [git issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5397) on this topic.

Comment: I'm guessing that calling it from MATLAB like that doesn't set the path correctly for the qhull module to find its DLLs. It looks like you're not passing any data into or out of the `pyrunfile` command, so can you create a batch file that does `conda activate Deep` then `python one_component_model.py` and call that from MATLAB with `system`?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Most probably the `pyenv` Matlab command doesn't activate your conda environment and that's why `qhull` fails to import. We do that behind the scenes in Spyder, so that's why you're not seeing any error with it.